# Magento 2 in how to remove the duplicate attributes?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, phtml, magento-2.1.9

I will Try to remove that but its not Working?

[image]

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attributes.phtml pages

 <?php
        $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        $_product = $block->getProduct()
    ?>
    <?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
        <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
            <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
                <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
                <tbody>                
                <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?> 
                    <?php if($_data['value'] == 'N/A') {

                    }elseif($block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label']))=="Is Featured"){

                        }elseif($_data['value']=='No'){
                        }else{
                        ?>                
        <tr>
            <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="col data yota-attribute-td" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>   
        <?php
        }  ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    <?php endif;?>

It's help you.
```